# grep: How to find words that starts with and end with

Tags: grep

How do I find a word that starts with "version" and ends with quote + space?

For example I want to look for words like:

```
version="1.0"
version="1.1.1"
version="1.2.1"
```

In a file that contains text like: blah version="1.2.1" blah

Thus, how can I use grep to find words that start with version=" and ends with quote+space?

I have tried:

```
grep -o '\version=".*"( |$)' filename
```

It returns nothing because nothing was found.

Comment: When you tried that, what results did you get, and what was wrong with those results?  What did you want to be different?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put a line ending character in an Or construct, every line ends with `$`.   `( |$)` means "space or line ending" but you want optional space", ` ?` for 0 or 1 or ` *`  for 0 or more.  I would recommend the latter because, why not make it as generic as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'version="[0-9.]+"(?= )' file
```